# FreeRadius Error reading /etc/freeradius/huntgroups

Tags: linux, ubuntu, radius, freeradius

I've configured freeradius to use sql, everything was working fine, I was doing some tests with the users, and suddenly I cannot start the debugger because of this error :

```
rlm_preprocess: Error reading /etc/freeradius/huntgroups
/etc/freeradius/modules/preprocess[13]: Instantiation failed for module "preprocess"
/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default[88]: Failed to load module "preprocess".
/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default[69]: Errors parsing authorize section.
```

I've never touched the files `preprocess` or `huntgroups`... I'm lost right now !!

Does anybody knows something about this ?

Full error trace:

```
FreeRADIUS Version 2.1.12, for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, built on Feb 24 2014 at 14:57:57
Copyright (C) 1999-2009 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors. 
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A 
PARTICULAR PURPOSE. 
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the 
GNU General Public License v2. 
Starting - reading configuration files ...
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/proxy.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/clients.conf
including files in directory /etc/freeradius/modules/
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/sqlcounter_expire_on_login
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/acct_unique
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/expiration
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/ippool
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/soh
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/sradutmp
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/redis
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/wimax
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/inner-eap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/logintime
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/exec
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/krb5
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/rediswho
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/etc_group
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/radutmp
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/dynamic_clients
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/counter
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/perl
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/mac2ip
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/files
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/detail.example.com
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/detail.log
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/sql_log
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/checkval
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/pam
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/digest
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/mschap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/ntlm_auth
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/otp
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/realm
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/opendirectory
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/attr_filter
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/ldap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/detail
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/passwd
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/linelog
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/smbpasswd
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/mac2vlan
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/smsotp
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/chap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/attr_rewrite
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/pap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/policy
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/unix
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/preprocess
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/always
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/expr
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/cui
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/echo
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/replicate
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/eap.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/sql.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/sql/mysql/dialup.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/sql/mysql/counter.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/policy.conf
including files in directory /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
main {
    user = "freerad"
    group = "freerad"
    allow_core_dumps = no
}
including dictionary file /etc/freeradius/dictionary
main {
    name = "freeradius"
    prefix = "/usr"
    localstatedir = "/var"
    sbindir = "/usr/sbin"
    logdir = "/var/log/freeradius"
    run_dir = "/var/run/freeradius"
    libdir = "/usr/lib/freeradius"
    radacctdir = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct"
    hostname_lookups = no
    max_request_time = 30
    cleanup_delay = 5
    max_requests = 1024
    pidfile = "/var/run/freeradius/freeradius.pid"
    checkrad = "/usr/sbin/checkrad"
    debug_level = 0
    proxy_requests = yes
 log {
    stripped_names = yes
    auth = yes
    auth_badpass = yes
    auth_goodpass = yes
 }
 security {
    max_attributes = 200
    reject_delay = 1
    status_server = yes
 }
}
radiusd: #### Loading Realms and Home Servers ####
 proxy server {
    retry_delay = 5
    retry_count = 3
    default_fallback = no
    dead_time = 120
    wake_all_if_all_dead = no
 }
 home_server localhost {
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
    port = 1812
    type = "auth"
    secret = "testing123"
    response_window = 20
    max_outstanding = 65536
    require_message_authenticator = yes
    zombie_period = 40
    status_check = "status-server"
    ping_interval = 30
    check_interval = 30
    num_answers_to_alive = 3
    num_pings_to_alive = 3
    revive_interval = 120
    status_check_timeout = 4
  coa {
    irt = 2
    mrt = 16
    mrc = 5
    mrd = 30
  }
 }
 home_server_pool my_auth_failover {
    type = fail-over
    home_server = localhost
 }
 realm example.com {
    auth_pool = my_auth_failover
 }
 realm LOCAL {
 }

radiusd: #### Instantiating modules ####
 instantiate {
 Module: Linked to module rlm_exec
 Module: Instantiating module "exec" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/exec
  exec {
    wait = no
    input_pairs = "request"
    shell_escape = yes
  }
 Module: Linked to module rlm_expr
 Module: Instantiating module "expr" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/expr
 Module: Linked to module rlm_expiration
 Module: Instantiating module "expiration" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/expiration
  expiration {
    reply-message = "Password Has Expired  "
  }
 Module: Linked to module rlm_logintime
 Module: Instantiating module "logintime" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/logintime
  logintime {
    reply-message = "You are calling outside your allowed timespan  "
    minimum-timeout = 60
  }
 }
radiusd: #### Loading Virtual Servers ####
server { # from file /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf
 modules {
  Module: Creating Auth-Type = digest
  Module: Creating Post-Auth-Type = REJECT
 Module: Checking authenticate {...} for more modules to load
 Module: Linked to module rlm_pap
 Module: Instantiating module "pap" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/pap
  pap {
    encryption_scheme = "auto"
    auto_header = no
  }
 Module: Linked to module rlm_chap
 Module: Instantiating module "chap" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/chap
 Module: Linked to module rlm_mschap
 Module: Instantiating module "mschap" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/mschap
  mschap {
    use_mppe = yes
    require_encryption = no
    require_strong = no
    with_ntdomain_hack = no
    allow_retry = yes
  }
 Module: Linked to module rlm_digest
 Module: Instantiating module "digest" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/digest
 Module: Linked to module rlm_unix
 Module: Instantiating module "unix" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/unix
  unix {
    radwtmp = "/var/log/freeradius/radwtmp"
  }
 Module: Linked to module rlm_eap
 Module: Instantiating module "eap" from file /etc/freeradius/eap.conf
  eap {
    default_eap_type = "md5"
    timer_expire = 60
    ignore_unknown_eap_types = no
    cisco_accounting_username_bug = no
    max_sessions = 4096
  }
 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_md5
 Module: Instantiating eap-md5
 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_leap
 Module: Instantiating eap-leap
 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_gtc
 Module: Instantiating eap-gtc
   gtc {
    challenge = "Password: "
    auth_type = "PAP"
   }
 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_tls
 Module: Instantiating eap-tls
   tls {
    rsa_key_exchange = no
    dh_key_exchange = yes
    rsa_key_length = 512
    dh_key_length = 512
    verify_depth = 0
    CA_path = "/etc/freeradius/certs"
    pem_file_type = yes
    private_key_file = "/etc/freeradius/certs/server.key"
    certificate_file = "/etc/freeradius/certs/server.pem"
    CA_file = "/etc/freeradius/certs/ca.pem"
    private_key_password = "whatever"
    dh_file = "/etc/freeradius/certs/dh"
    random_file = "/dev/urandom"
    fragment_size = 1024
    include_length = yes
    check_crl = no
    cipher_list = "DEFAULT"
    make_cert_command = "/etc/freeradius/certs/bootstrap"
    ecdh_curve = "prime256v1"
    cache {
    enable = no
    lifetime = 24
    max_entries = 255
    }
    verify {
    }
    ocsp {
    enable = no
    override_cert_url = yes
    url = "http://127.0.0.1/ocsp/"
    }
   }
 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_ttls
 Module: Instantiating eap-ttls
   ttls {
    default_eap_type = "md5"
    copy_request_to_tunnel = no
    use_tunneled_reply = no
    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
    include_length = yes
   }
 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_peap
 Module: Instantiating eap-peap
   peap {
    default_eap_type = "mschapv2"
    copy_request_to_tunnel = no
    use_tunneled_reply = no
    proxy_tunneled_request_as_eap = yes
    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
    soh = no
   }
 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_mschapv2
 Module: Instantiating eap-mschapv2
   mschapv2 {
    with_ntdomain_hack = no
    send_error = no
   }
 Module: Checking authorize {...} for more modules to load
 Module: Linked to module rlm_preprocess
 Module: Instantiating module "preprocess" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/preprocess
  preprocess {
    huntgroups = "/etc/freeradius/huntgroups"
    hints = "/etc/freeradius/hints"
    with_ascend_hack = no
    ascend_channels_per_line = 23
    with_ntdomain_hack = no
    with_specialix_jetstream_hack = no
    with_cisco_vsa_hack = no
    with_alvarion_vsa_hack = no
  }
rlm_preprocess: Error reading /etc/freeradius/huntgroups
/etc/freeradius/modules/preprocess[13]: Instantiation failed for module "preprocess"
/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default[88]: Failed to load module "preprocess".
/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default[69]: Errors parsing authorize section.
```

---

**Edit**

- Could be possible the issue is about permissions ?
- I make a backup of the folder `freeradius` and then make:

  `chown -R freerad:freerad freeradius/`

Everything works now, but I'm not very confortable with this...

- Can anyone tell me wich are the right permissions for this folder and it files ?

I'm thinking about a clean remove and install again to avoid more issues...

Comment: And is there a huntgroups file ? It can be empty if you don't need it...

Comment: @Dom Yes, there is `huntgroups` file, all lines are commented

Comment: If I empty the file huntgroups, the error changes to: `Error: rlm_preprocess: Error reading /etc/freeradius/hints`